# find and grep command this but not that

Tags: shell, find, grep

I am trying to find all the files which are not the `*.o (object)` files and store in file MyFile.lst in the current directory Tree.

I am doing it from using below command.

```
     #! /usr/bin/ksh
     find . -type f | grep -v "*.o" >> MyFile.lst
```

For some reason it is not working please help me.

**Edit:**

```
find . -type f | grep -v '\.o$' >> MyFile.lst
```

Seems like working. Any comment/ suggestion.(added keith.layne correction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `grep`.

```
find . -type f  '!' -name '*.o' >> MyFile.lst
```

In grep, the searching pattern should be a regular expression. Therefore, `.`, `$` and `*` are having special meaning.

```
.  means match any character
$  means match the end of a line
X* means match X, zero or more times(greedy)
```

`grep -v '\.o$'` would match files with `.o` extension. (You need to escape `.` for its literal meaning).

Comment: Agreed, for a simple case like this you don't need all of `grep`'s goodness.  Your version should be faster for big file trees too, right?

Comment: I don't know about `ksh`, but it might be worth noting (for any future viewers) that the `!` would need escaping in `bash`

Comment: @carlpett: i checked it with -x flag in bash. it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your edit should be fine...`$` (as I'm sure you know) should match the end of the line.

You should make one change, however: escape the `.` (a wildcard) with a `\`.  Otherwise you'll match for example a file named 'Mo'.

I think (from a quick test) that `grep` treats `*` as a literal at the beginning of a pattern.

Your script will now be:

```
#! /usr/bin/ksh
find . -type f | grep -v '\.o$' >> MyFile.lst
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -not -name "*.o" -type f >> list
```